# Run nodejs script on button click

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

please can someone explain how I can made this nodejs script run when a button is clicked?

```
var Twit = require('twit');
var t = new Twit({
consumer_key: '******',
consumer_secret: '******',
access_token: '******',
access_token_secret: '******',
});

t.post('statuses/update', {status:'hello world'},function(err, data, response){
console.log(data);
});
```

Currently I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You will need to have a NodeJS process running as a server in which a callback can be hooked to an API endpoint which will then be run when you click on a button in a website.

1. Client gets HTML with button (from a webserver of any type)
2. Client clicks on button
3. HTTP request is sent to NodeJS server at a particular url (yourip.com/yourscript)
4. NodeJS server calls a function that you assigned to that particular URL

Answer (score 2):

NodeJS is used on the **server-side**, and can be described as an extension of JavaScript which can do more stuff, like file operations.

Normal JavaScript is used on the **client-side**.

Therefore, you cannot just use nodeJS in the browser, because the browser is lacking features that nodeJS offers. What you can do is use nodeJS to build an API and connect the API to the client-side script. You will need a server for this to work, though.